# Http request in clojurescript with re-frame

Tags: clojurescript, re-frame

I use Clojurescript + Reframe + http-fx.
This is example src for http request:

```
(re-frame/reg-event-fx
 ::request-login 
 (fn [{:keys [db]} [_ req-data]]  
   {:db   (assoc db :loading true)
    :http-xhrio {:method          :post
                 :uri             "http://localhost:8002/api/auth/login"
                 :params          req-data
                 :timeout         8000      
                 :format          (ajax/json-request-format)
                 :response-format (ajax/json-response-format {:keywords? true})
                 :on-success      [::response-login-success]
                 :on-failure      [:bad-http-result]}}))
```

My dev shadow-cljs works on http://localhost:8280/

But my api server on http://localhost:8002/ (this is other application).

The library does not allow me to make requests to servers at other addresses.
Only for (:uri "http://localhost:8280/api/auth/login")

In browser inspector displays: Provisional headers are shown! This is due to the referrer parameter in header, as I understand it.

I tryed:

```
 :uri     "http://localhost:8002/api/auth/login"
 :params  req-data
 :headers {"referer" "http://localhost:8002/" "origin" "http://localhost:8002"}
```

It does not help!
I found information that it is necessary to do not an asynchronous request.

I was able to run only this solution (call JS function from Clojurescript):

```
function myAjaxPost() {
    const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.open("POST", "http://localhost:8002/api/auth/login", false);
    xhttp.send(JSON.stringify({login:"user1",password:"pswd1"}));
    console.log(xhttp.responseText);
};
```

But How it is possible to set async mode for http-fx?

It is possible to make requests for a different URLs?

Comment: What do you mean by "does not allow"? Are there any errors?

Comment: In browser inspector displays: Provisional headers are shown! This is due to the referrer parameter in header, as I understand it.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem. The problem was with the server.
Enabled on the server: Enable All CORS Requests.
And everything worked!!!
Maybe this will help someone.